# How to resolve variable before completing calculation?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for a way to use a cell reference instead of a sheet reference.

[image: Here is a small worksheet I made to show this.]

Cell B2 has the formula:`=COUNTIF(VM!B:B,"Powered On")`

The "VM" page would have a list of servers and their power status.

I am looking for a way to make cell B2 reference another cell for the sheet name instead of having to change the sheet name in each formula.

For example: `=COUNTIF(A2!B:B,"Powered On")` `A2` being a cell that has the name "VM" in it.

Here is an image of the desired command/method:
[image: Here is an image of the desired command/method.]

I tried `(A2)` as well hoping it would resolve the name and then use that in the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDIRECT()

The indirect takes a string and turns it into a valid reference.

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "'!B:B"),"Powered On")
```

So in the case above it would create a string `"'VM'!B:B"`.  Then the Indirect will turn it into a valid cell reference.

The B:B reference, since it is literal text, will not change if the formula is copied or dragged to another cell.

The A2 which is a cell reference and is relative will change as it is copied or dragged to different cells.